# arduino cant turn on the infra red sensor from raspberry pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi3, arduino-uno

so recently make iot smart remote, so I want to turn on the ir trasnmiter in arduino when I push turn on from my web service , can anyoone tell me how to make it happen thank you or can anyone suggest where can learn about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem and not over-engineer it you should only use an Arduino, and ESP32 or other ESP versions. It's cheap and easy to use. By the way ESP32 is what the majority IoT-manufacturers use in there electronics. There are plenty of ESP32, ESP14, ESP8266 boards, small ones, big ones, ones with cameras and display and with or without Bluetooth, BLE and Wifi.

### ESP14

[image: ESP32]

### ESP8266

[image: ESP8266]

Here is a good tutorial for setting up an [WebServer on ESP32](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-web-server-arduino-ide/).

Just replace the blink led part in the tutorial with your transmitting the IR-signal code and you good to go.